# EF Core - Select all columns using EF.Functions.Like

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm searching a large view on a SQL Server database using EF Core 3.1.4 (table names obfuscated).

```
var query = searchModel.SearchQuery.ToUpper();

list = list.Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.name0.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name1.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name2.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name3.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name4.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name5.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name6.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name7.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name8.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name9.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(s.name10.ToUpper(), $"%{query}%"));
```

Is there a way to just select all columns instead of adding an or operator in the `Where` condition for each column?

Comment: No there's not (unless you construct the expression manually with some reflection). Also it is highly unlikely you need the ToUpper calls. The default collation for sql server (at least for English language installs) is case insensitive. You havent indicted what version of efcore you are using but I'm fairly certain that version 3+ doesn't like this

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I've edited my answer with the correct version. Without the .ToUpper calls is doesn't work as intended - some fields are queried properly, some aren't. It is an old database that I cannot alter so everything needs to be done in code.

Comment: If you want an answer that includes constructing the expression manually, you'll need to indicate how it should work. Is it all string/text columns? A subset of those columns (ie any column starting with 'name')? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to read the schema of the DB through the Entity Framework, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455279/how-to-get-column-name-and-corresponding-database-type-from-dbcontext-in-entity) as a starting point. Once you have a list of the column names, you could write a static or extension method `IsLikeAColumn`, used like `Where(s => IsLikeAColumn(s))`, looking something like:

```
bool match = false;
foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
{
    match |= EF.Functions.Like(columnName, $"%{query}%");
}
return match;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not possible at all and even in SQL server also its not possible. Even in C# `If` and `While` also you can not do this. You should have multiple conditions with comparison operators

Comment: In SQL you could union all columns but I doubt it would give any benefits. `select * from (select name0 as q from list union all select name1 from list ...) c where q like '%query%'`